# Permission denied when calling SHAP

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, permissions, shap

I am using Jupyter Notebook and my OS is windows. I wanted to call shap library using the code `!pip install shap` but I got this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shap'`

I have already installed shap in windows Command Prompt by `pip install shap`
After that I tried to install that on my notebook with `!pip install shap` too, but I got this error

```
"ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\packaging-20.9.dist-info\\direct_url.json'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions."
```

I don't know what permission it needs. and how I could solve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pip install shap --user
```